# Passing Params to href in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am reading other engineers code to undersntad some stuff and here is one:

```
  %a{href: scores_organizations_path(organization_id: summary.id), class: ('not-eligible' unless summary.scores_score.present?)}
```

The part that they are passing a parameter to the _path was new to me, I had never seen this before.

```
<a href="/scores/organizations?organization_id=6297552">
```

This is intresting, so we can dynamically pass params to the links?

Where is this in Rails guides? Or any other reaource that I can read more details about it and learn it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read more about routing here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Although, this code does seem a bit strange. I would write the same thing as such:

```
= link_to "Link Title", scores_organizations_path(@organization)
```

As you can see, there's no need to specify the id manually. This translates to:

```
/scores/organizations/:id
```

You could still pass optional params:

```
= link_to "Link Title", scores_organizations_path(@organization, foo: 'bar')
```

You can [read more on link helpers here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to).

Comment: The only thing I would add is point the OP to the [link_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to) documentation, which is a bit clearer concerning the examples, imho. But great answer.

Comment: Maybe they did it that way to pass a "named parameter" of @organization so they can explicitly access it somewhere else too?

Comment: @EricFromSouthPark my guess: either the link is wrong, or they don't use restful routes, and in `index` they check if a `organization_id` was given and then return only one organization. That works, just not very restful :)